# How to write and read an array of objects to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, writefile

I have this array of objects:

var people = {name:'list 1',mode:0,friends:[{user:1,code:'red'},{user:2,code:'blue'}]};

I want to write it to a file so if the node server crashes I dont lose the data. I did this:

```
//define variables from file
var file = "../../people.txt";
var open = fs.readFileSync(file);
va data = open.toString();
var name = data.name;
var mode = data.mode;
var friends = data.friends;
```

whenever a variable changes I save it to a file like this:

```
function update() {
 //dosomething
 name = 'new list';
 mode = 1;
 friends = [{user:4,code:'red'},{user:6,code:'blue'}]

fs.writeFileSync(file,`{name:'${name}',mode:${mode},friends:${friends}'}`,{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'});
}
```

This is output onto the file

```
{name:'list 1',mode:0,friends:[object, object]}
```

and the data cant be read at all. What am I supposed to do here?

Thank you.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: You should convert the JSON data into a string format using `JSON.stringify` before writing in to a file, and when reading them out, you should parse the string into JSON using `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the JSON data into a string format using `JSON.stringify()` before writing it to a file, and when reading them out, you should parse the string into JSON using `JSON.parse()`

More details are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-json-parse-stringify) and [how to read/write JSON files](https://heynode.com/tutorial/readwrite-json-files-nodejs/)

Comment: I tried but not working. Im reading it like this: `var data = JSON.parse(open.toString());` and write it like this:  `fs.writeFileSync(file,JSON.stringify(`{name:'${name}',mode:${mode},friends:${friends}'}`),{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'});`

Comment: https://heynode.com/tutorial/readwrite-json-files-nodejs/ @CainNuke Here's the detailed description. Hope it helps!